# Brazilian zip code javascript API

Tags: javascript, zip

I want a javascript API to auto fill the brazilian zip codes.

I need it in JSONP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very good one:

http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/02011200.js

Response:

correiocontrolcep({“bairro”: “Santana”, “logradouro”: “Rua Volunt\u00e1rios da P\u00e1tria”, “cep”: “02011200″, “uf”: “SP”, “localidade”: “S\u00e3o Paulo”});